# clang can remove function call when order of designated initializers does not correspond to fields declaration

Tags: c++, clang++, designated-initializer

this code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Acc {
    int a;
};
struct Buu {
    int b;
};

struct Foo {
    const Acc& acc;
    Buu& buu;
};

void printInfo( const Foo& ) {
    std::cout << "hi!" << std::endl;
}

void call( Buu& buu ) {
    Acc acc = { 1 };
    Foo foo = {
        .acc = acc,
        .buu = buu,
    };
    std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
    printInfo( foo );
    std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
void noCall( Buu& buu ) {
    Acc acc = { 1 };
    Foo foo = {
        .buu = buu,
        .acc = acc,
    };
    std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
    printInfo( foo );
    std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Buu buu = { 2 };
    call( buu );
    noCall( buu );
    return 0;
}
```

when compliled by clang (I tried 3.7.0, 3.7.1) will out:

```
before
hi!
after
before
after
```

The second call of `printInfo` was removed... Difference between `call` and `noCall` only in order of designated initializers.

With `-pedantic` option it will produce warnings that designated initializers is the feature of C99 but not C++ but still create code without the second call of `printInfo`.

Is it known bug?

Comment: g++ thorws *sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported*.  Clang might not support it as well but instead of issuing an error it just drops the code.

Comment: @NathanOliver clang's attitude towards UB and things not in the standard: http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/012/861/520.jpg

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko LMAO.  I think  that how most compilers behave.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think that at least a diagnostic should be issued because it is incorrect syntax according to the standard and it is not a **supported** extension either, because the generated code discards the offending lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is at least unfair if not a bug, because the warning is only at pedandic level when Clang simply removes all references to `foo` in function `nocall`. We can confirm it by looking at assembly code in debug mode (`c++ -S -g file.cpp`) to see exactly how the compiler interprets each and every line.

When we look at the .s genererated file, we can see that in call, lines 20 `Foo foo = {...` and 25 `printInfo(foo)` are generated:

```
    .loc    1 20 0                  # ess.cpp:20:0
    movq    %rcx, -64(%rbp)
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rcx
.Ltmp45:
    movq    %rcx, -56(%rbp)
    .loc    1 24 0                  # ess.cpp:24:0
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc
    leaq    -64(%rbp), %rdi
    leaq    _ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_, %rcx
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, -32(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    .loc    5 322 0                 # /usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:322:0
.Ltmp46:
    movq    %rdi, -72(%rbp)         # 8-byte Spill
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   *-32(%rbp)
.Ltmp47:
    .loc    1 25 0                  # ess.cpp:25:0
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rdi         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    %rax, -80(%rbp)         # 8-byte Spill
    callq   _Z9printInfoRK3Foo
    leaq    _ZNSt3__14coutE, %rdi
    leaq    .L.str2, %rsi
```

But for nocall, the corresponding lines (30 and 35) are not:

```
    .loc    1 29 0 prologue_end     # ess.cpp:29:0
.Ltmp57:
    movl    .L_ZZ6noCallR3BuuE3acc, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, -48(%rbp)
    .loc    1 34 0                  # ess.cpp:34:0
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc
    leaq    _ZNSt3__14coutE, %rdi
    leaq    .L.str2, %rsi
    leaq    _ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_, %rdx
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -32(%rbp)
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
    .loc    5 322 0                 # /usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:322:0
.Ltmp58:
    movq    %rdi, -72(%rbp)         # 8-byte Spill
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq    %rsi, -80(%rbp)         # 8-byte Spill
    callq   *-32(%rbp)
.Ltmp59:
    .loc    1 36 0                  # ess.cpp:36:0
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rdi         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rsi         # 8-byte Reload
    movq    %rax, -88(%rbp)         # 8-byte Spill
    callq   _ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc
    leaq    _ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_, %rdx
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdi
    .loc    5 322 0                 # /usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:322:0
.Ltmp60:
    callq   *-16(%rbp)
.Ltmp61:
    .loc    1 37 0                  # ess.cpp:37:0
```

Where the numbered lines in the cpp file are:

```
18  void call( Buu& buu ) {
19      Acc acc = { 1 };
20      Foo foo = {
21          .acc = acc,
22          .buu = buu,
23      };
24      std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
25      printInfo( foo );
26      std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
27  }
28  void noCall( Buu& buu ) {
29      Acc acc = { 1 };
30      Foo foo = {
31              .buu = buu,
32              .acc = acc
33      };
34      std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
35      printInfo( foo );
36      std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
37  }
```

My understanding is that clang pretends to process the C99 syntax in C++ mode when it does not.

---

IMHO, this is a bug that could be reported to clang, because at least a diagnostic should be issued per 1.4 Implementation compliance [intro.compliance]

> 1 **The set of diagnosable rules consists of all syntactic and semantic rules in this International Standard** except
>   for those rules containing an explicit notation that “no diagnostic is required” or which are described as
>   resulting in “undefined behavior.”
>   
> 2 Although this International Standard states only requirements on C++ implementations, those requirements
>   are often easier to understand if they are phrased as requirements on programs, parts of programs, or
>   execution of programs. Such requirements have the following meaning:
>
> - If a program contains no violations of the rules in this International Standard, a conforming implementation
>     shall, within its resource limits, accept and correctly execute2 that program.
> - If a program contains **a violation of any diagnosable rule** or an occurrence of a construct described in
>     this Standard as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support that construct,
>     **a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message**.
>
> ...
> 8 A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
>   not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. **Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
>   use such extensions that are ill-formed** according to this International Standard. Having done so, however,
>   they can compile and execute such programs.